# Access data in different databases from a view

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I need to know the number of records that there are in any table from any database of a SQL Server Instance with a variable number of databases inside it.

The number of records at each table is obtained from a view called 'webTableCount' based on sys.objects and sys.indexes. This view exists in all the databases.

What I need is a query that given a row with a specific DataBaseName and TableName, it returns the number of rows that the table has in the database.

I want to create a User Defined Function to do that, the problem is that I can do it by using dynamic SQL but dynamic SQL cannot be used in UDF, so I'm stuck at this point.

I show how I would do with dynamic SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNumberOfRecords]
(
  @Database AS VARCHAR(128),
  @TabName AS VARCHAR(128),

  DECLARE @cnt INT
  DECLARE @EXECSQL AS NVARCHAR(2000)

  SET @ExecSQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 @cnt = RecordCount FROM ['
        + @Database + '].[dbo].[webTableCount] ' + 
        ' WHERE [TABLE] = '''  + @TabName + '''  '  

  @ExecSQL, N'@cnt int out'

  RETURN @cnt

END
```

Is there any way to determine dynamically in a UDF the database from where you must extract some information?

Thanks,
Sergio